# Incorrect skeleton mesh drawn using Assimp and OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es, assimp

I'm trying to draw a skeleton animation mesh(model boblampclean.md5mesh) using ASSIMP but meshes are drawn incorrectly. Meshes are loaded correctly I'm following ogld tutorials for loading and drawing meshes. Below is my some code and output:

This is how buffers are populated and initially VAO, VBO and EBO are generated:

```
    GLCall(glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Positions.size() * sizeof(m_Positions[0]),&m_Positions[0],GL_STATIC_DRAW))
    GLCall(glEnableVertexAttribArray(POSITION_LOCATION))
    GLCall(glVertexAttribPointer(POSITION_LOCATION, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,nullptr))

    GLCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Buffers[TEXCOORD_VB]))
    GLCall(glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_TexCoords.size() * sizeof(m_TexCoords[0]),&m_TexCoords[0],GL_STATIC_DRAW))
    GLCall(glEnableVertexAttribArray(TEX_COORD_LOCATION))
    GLCall(glVertexAttribPointer(TEX_COORD_LOCATION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr))

    GLCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Buffers[NORMAL_VB]))
    GLCall(glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Normals.size() * sizeof(m_Normals[0]), &m_Normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW))
    GLCall(glEnableVertexAttribArray(NORMAL_LOCATION))
    GLCall(glVertexAttribPointer(NORMAL_LOCATION, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr))

    GLCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Buffers[BONE_VB]))
    GLCall(glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Bones.size() * sizeof(m_Bones[0]), &m_Bones[0],GL_STATIC_DRAW))

    GLCall(glEnableVertexAttribArray(BONE_ID_LOCATION))
    GLCall(glVertexAttribIPointer(BONE_ID_LOCATION, MAX_NUM_BONES_PER_VERTEX, GL_INT,sizeof(VertexBoneData), nullptr))

    GLCall(glEnableVertexAttribArray(BONE_WEIGHT_LOCATION))
    GLCall(glVertexAttribPointer(BONE_WEIGHT_LOCATION, MAX_NUM_BONES_PER_VERTEX, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,sizeof(VertexBoneData),(const GLvoid *) (MAX_NUM_BONES_PER_VERTEX * sizeof(int32_t))))

    GLCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Buffers[INDEX_BUFFER]))
    GLCall(glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Indices.size() * sizeof(m_Indices[0]), &m_Indices[0],GL_STATIC_DRAW))
```

Draw call:

```
    GLCall(glUseProgram(meshProgram))
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(45.0f,
                                                (float) windowWidth / (float) windowHeight,
                                                0.1f,
                                                100.0f);
        glm::mat4 translate = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f));
        glm::mat4 rotation = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::radians(120.0f),
                                         glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
        glm::mat4 scale = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0), glm::vec3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2));
        glm::mat4 model = translate * rotation * scale;
        GLCall(GLuint projectionLocation = meshShader->getUniformLocation("projection"))
        GLCall(GLuint modelLocation = meshShader->getUniformLocation("model"))
        meshCamera->useCamera();

        std::vector<Matrix4f> boneMatrix;
        mesh->GetBoneTransforms(mesh->getAnimationSecond(), boneMatrix);

        GLuint mBoneLocation[100];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE_IN_ELEMENTS(mBoneLocation); i++) {
            char Name[128];
            memset(Name, 0, sizeof(Name));
            snprintf(Name, sizeof(Name), "gBones[%d]", i);
            GLCall(mBoneLocation[i] = meshShader->getUniformLocation(Name))
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < boneMatrix.size(); ++i) {
            if (i >= 100) {
                break;
            }
            Matrix4f matrix = boneMatrix[i];
            GLCall(glUniformMatrix4fv(mBoneLocation[i], 1, GL_TRUE, (const GLfloat *) matrix))
        }

        // GLCall(GLuint meshTextureLocation = meshShader->getUniformLocation("texture"))
        GLCall(meshShader->setUniformMatrix4fv(projectionLocation, 1, glm::value_ptr(projection)))
        GLCall(meshShader->setUniformMatrix4fv(modelLocation, 1, glm::value_ptr(model)))

        Vector3f localPos = mesh->GetWorldTransform().WorldPosToLocalPos(meshCamera->getCameraPos());
        GLCall(GLuint localCameraPosLocation = meshShader->getUniformLocation("gCameraLocalPos"))
        GLCall(glUniform3f(localCameraPosLocation, localPos.x, localPos.y, localPos.z))[![enter image description here][1]][1]

        GLCall(glBindVertexArray(m_VAO))

        for (auto &m_Meshe : m_Meshes) {

            unsigned int MaterialIndex = m_Meshe.MaterialIndex;

            if (m_Materials[MaterialIndex].pDiffuse) {
                Texture *texture = m_Materials[MaterialIndex].pDiffuse;
                GLCall(texture->bind())
                GLCall(GLuint diffuseLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, "gSampler"))
                GLCall(glUniform1i(diffuseLocation, texture->getSlot()))
            }
            if (m_Materials[MaterialIndex].pSpecularExponent) {
                Texture *texture = m_Materials[MaterialIndex].pSpecularExponent;
                GLCall(GLuint specularLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program,
                               "gSamplerSpecularExponent"))
                GLCall(texture->bind())
                GLCall(glUniform1i(specularLocation, texture->getSlot()))
            }

            GLCall(glDrawElementsBaseVertex(GL_TRIANGLES, m_Meshe.NumIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
                                            (GLvoid *) (sizeof(unsigned int) * m_Meshe.BaseIndex),
                                            m_Meshe.BaseVertex))

        }
        GLCall(glBindVertexArray(0))
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Comment: “meshes are drawn incorrectly” is vague. Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXlrC.png this is the link of image. @Andrea

Comment: @Andrea screenshot added in question as well.

Comment: I see, so it looks like complete nonsense. This kind of thing is hard to fix since all sorts of things could be wrong. The best advice I can give is to try to simplify your code as much as possible (including removing features) so you get a case that's simple enough you can figure out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by storing normals, vertices and Texchord correctly.